# How can I save indexes while converting a LaTeX file to ODT?

Tags: tex4ht, conversion, pandoc

Recently, I have completed a LaTeX document where I had created two indexes using the `\splitidx` package, the index entries marked with `\sindex` terms. For example,

```
\documentclass[b5paper,polish]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{splitidx}
\makeindex
\newindex[Alphabetical index]{idx}
\newindex[Films index]{film}
\begin{document}
This is the first entry\sindex[idx]{The first entry}. And this is the 
second one\sindex[film]{The second entry}.
\printindex{idx}
\printindex{film}
\end{document}
```

Because of the publishing issues, though, I have to convert the document at least to an ODT file. Converting bibliography isn't much of a problem; the major issue is that the converted file (using either Pandoc or tex4ht) doesn't contain indexes at all. Therefore, I wonder if it is possible to force any of the aforementioned converters to put the index entries into the ODT file. Or is there any more indirect way to do that? I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: I can produce index using TeX4ht, but links to the index destination don't work correctly. I will take a look at this issue next week, I will be offline for next few days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to produce index with TeX4ht. You need the development version of [`make4ht`](https://github.com/michal-h21/make4ht), because I had to fix some issues regarding hyper links in the ODT output.

It also needs updated `oo-text.4xt` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE xtpipes SYSTEM "xtpipes.dtd" >
<!-- oo-text.4xt (2020-02-25-09:37), generated from tex4ht-oo-xtpipes.tex
     Copyright (C) 2009-2013 TeX Users Group
     Copyright (C) 2006-2009 Eitan M. Gurari
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated. -->
<xtpipes preamble="yes" signature="oo-text.4xt (2020-02-25-09:37)">
   <sax content-handler="xtpipes.util.ScriptsManager,tex4ht.OoFilter"
        lexical-handler="xtpipes.util.ScriptsManagerLH" >
      <script element="text:bibliography-mark" >
         <set name="bib-mark" >
   <![CDATA[
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"

      xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0"
      xmlns:style="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:style:1.0"
      xmlns:text="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0"
      xmlns:table="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0"
      xmlns:draw="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:drawing:1.0"
      xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
      xmlns:meta="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:meta:1.0"
      xmlns:number="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:datastyle:1.0"
      xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlns:chart="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:chart:1.0"
      xmlns:dr3d="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:dr3d:1.0"
      xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
      xmlns:form="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:form:1.0"
      xmlns:script="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:script:1.0"
      xmlns:ooo="http://openoffice.org/2004/office"
      xmlns:ooow="http://openoffice.org/2004/writer"
      xmlns:oooc="http://openoffice.org/2004/calc"
      xmlns:dom="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
      xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   >
      <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration = "yes" />

    <xsl:template match="text:bibliography-mark" >
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:attribute name="text:identifier">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
     </xsl:attribute>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
   </xsl:copy>
   <text:span>
      <xsl:attribute name="text:style-name">
         <xsl:text>reference-ref</xsl:text>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <text:reference-ref>
        <xsl:attribute name="text:ref-name">
              <xsl:value-of
                 select="text:span/text:reference-ref/@text:ref-name"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="text:reference-format">
              <xsl:text>text</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
      </text:reference-ref>
   </text:span>
</xsl:template>

         <xsl:template match="*|@*|text()|comment()" >
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()|comment()" />
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
]]>

</set>
<xslt name="." xml="." xsl="bib-mark" />

      </script>
      <script element="table:table" >
         <dom name="." xml="." method="table" class="tex4ht.OoUtilities" />

      </script>
      <script element="text:p" >
         <set name="text-p" >
   <![CDATA[
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"

      xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0"
      xmlns:style="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:style:1.0"
      xmlns:text="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0"
      xmlns:table="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0"
      xmlns:draw="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:drawing:1.0"
      xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
      xmlns:meta="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:meta:1.0"
      xmlns:number="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:datastyle:1.0"
      xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlns:chart="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:chart:1.0"
      xmlns:dr3d="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:dr3d:1.0"
      xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
      xmlns:form="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:form:1.0"
      xmlns:script="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:script:1.0"
      xmlns:ooo="http://openoffice.org/2004/office"
      xmlns:ooow="http://openoffice.org/2004/writer"
      xmlns:oooc="http://openoffice.org/2004/calc"
      xmlns:dom="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
      xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   >
      <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration = "yes" />

   <xsl:template match="text:p[ (count(child::*)=1)
                             and child::draw:frame
                             and parent::text:p
                           ]" >
    <xsl:apply-templates select="child::draw:frame" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="text:p[
     child::text:p
   and
     (count(child::text:p) = count(child::*))
 ]" >
   <!--xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="text:style-name">
          <xsl:text>start_</xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="@text:style-name" />
      </xsl:attribute-->
      <xsl:comment>
          <xsl:text>start </xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select=" @text:style-name " />
     </xsl:comment>
   <!--/xsl:copy-->
       <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()|comment()" mode="nested-p" />
   <!--xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="text:style-name">
          <xsl:text>end</xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="@text:style-name" />
      </xsl:attribute-->
      <xsl:comment>
          <xsl:text>end_</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select=" @text:style-name " />
     </xsl:comment>
   <!--/xsl:copy-->
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*[not(text:p)]|text()|comment()" mode="nested-p" >
  <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="text:p" mode="nested-p" >
  <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="text:style-name">
         <xsl:value-of select="parent::text:p/@text:style-name" />
         <xsl:text>_</xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="@text:style-name" />
         <xsl:text>_</xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="child::*[1]/@text:style-name" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[ name() != 'text:style-name' ]" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()|comment()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

   <xsl:template
    match="text:p[
              parent::text:p/@text:style-name='printthebibliography-dd'
          ]"
    mode="nested-p" >
  <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="text:style-name">
         <xsl:value-of select="'printthebibliography-dd'" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[ name() != 'text:style-name' ]" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()|comment()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="text:p[  child::text:span[
                       starts-with(@text:style-name, 'multicolumn-')
                     ] ]" >
   <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates
            select="child::text:span[
                       starts-with(@text:style-name, 'multicolumn-') ]
                    /@*
                   " />
       <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()|comment()" />
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="text:span[
                       starts-with(@text:style-name, 'multicolumn-') ]" />

         <xsl:template match="*|@*|text()|comment()" >
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()|comment()" />
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
]]>

</set>
<xslt name="." xml="." xsl="text-p" />

      </script>
      <script element="text:h" >
         <set name="headers" >
   <![CDATA[
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"

      xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0"
      xmlns:style="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:style:1.0"
      xmlns:text="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0"
      xmlns:table="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0"
      xmlns:draw="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:drawing:1.0"
      xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
      xmlns:meta="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:meta:1.0"
      xmlns:number="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:datastyle:1.0"
      xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlns:chart="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:chart:1.0"
      xmlns:dr3d="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:dr3d:1.0"
      xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
      xmlns:form="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:form:1.0"
      xmlns:script="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:script:1.0"
      xmlns:ooo="http://openoffice.org/2004/office"
      xmlns:ooow="http://openoffice.org/2004/writer"
      xmlns:oooc="http://openoffice.org/2004/calc"
      xmlns:dom="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
      xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   >
      <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration = "yes" />

   <xsl:template match="text:h[@text:style-name='algorithmic-dt']" >
  <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()|comment()" mode="algorithmic"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*|@*|comment()" mode="algorithmic" >
  <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()|comment()" mode="algorithmic"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="text()" mode="algorithmic" >
   <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,' ','&#xA0;')"/>
</xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="text:h[
     (@text:style-name='printthebibliography-dt')
     and
     (normalize-space()='')
]" >
</xsl:template>

         <xsl:template match="*|@*|text()|comment()" >
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()|comment()" />
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
]]>

</set>
<xslt name="." xml="." xsl="headers" />

      </script>
   </sax>
</xtpipes>
```

This file is used for some validation issues of the ODT file.

I've also had to fix your TeX file, because you used incorrect version of `\printindex` command. You need to use `\printindex[film]` instead of `\printindex{film}`.

```
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/529524/2891
\documentclass[b5paper,polish]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{splitidx}
\makeindex
\newindex[Alphabetical index]{idx}
\newindex[Films index]{film}
\begin{document}
This is the first entry\sindex[idx]{The first entry}. And this is the 
second one\sindex[film]{The second entry}.
\printindex[idx]
\printindex[film]
\end{document}
```

To execute the indexing command, use the following build file, `mybuild.lua`:

```
Make:htlatex {}
Make:xindex {}
Make:htlatex {}
```

Compile your document using

```
make4ht -f odt -e mybuild.lua filename.tex
```

This is the result in LibreOffice:

[image]